# Loop with BeautifulSoup doesn't find all links iterating across all document

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, beautifulsoup, hyperlink

**Introduction and Explaination**

I have been trying to learn how to scrape multiple links (I can handle one relatively well), and after watching many a tutorial I was able to put together the below code. Now the code itself works for creating a beautiful soup object, but it is not grabbing the entirety of the different pages. The postings go from 120-3000 and if I clean the data in the file I get 83 entries. Does anyone have any advice on what I missed and why my loop isnt iterating across the 25 or so pages?

Edit: To be clear I am trying to pull the html content of 25 pages, or 3000 entries worth of data into the soup object. From there I can clean the data to analyze fine, its just pulling all the data across the pages that doesnt appear to be working as Im only getting the first 120, or 1 pages worth.

**My Code**

```
pages = np.arange(120, 3000, 120)
for page in pages:
    page = requests.get("https://sandiego.craigslist.org/d/apartments-housing-for-rent/search/apa?s=" + str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    sleep(randint(2,10))

soup
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause there is no information in your question, that describes the value of pages, I guess you set it to *25*. If so, you have to multiply it in the loop by *120*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get("https://sandiego.craigslist.org/d/apartments-housing-for-rent/search/apa?s="+str(page*120)).text, 'lxml')
```

**Example (sequence of numbers from 0 to 4)**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time, random

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

itemList = []

for page in range(5):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get("https://sandiego.craigslist.org/d/apartments-housing-for-rent/search/apa?s="+str(page*120)).text, 'lxml')
    itemList.append(soup.select('li.result-row h3'))
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1.8,5.2))

#flatten of itemList
itemList = [item for sublist in itemList for item in sublist]
```

**Output (600 items)**

```
[...,<h3 class="result-heading">
 <a class="result-title hdrlnk" data-id="7261621307" href="https://sandiego.craigslist.org/nsd/apa/d/san-marcos-2bath-manufactured-home-55/7261621307.html" id="postid_7261621307">2bath Manufactured Home 55+ San Marcos</a>
 </h3>,
 <h3 class="result-heading">
 <a class="result-title hdrlnk" data-id="7271245407" href="https://sandiego.craigslist.org/nsd/apa/d/san-marcos-fully-upgraded-renovated/7271245407.html" id="postid_7271245407">Fully upgraded, renovated, large 1BR/1BA! Call Today!</a>
 </h3>]
```

Comment: HedgeHog, that was helpful. I tried to update the original question with a bit more information.

Comment: Was anyone else able to test my code? I am still stumped why it isnt going through the pages like it should?